# Resize UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uialertview

Is there any way I could resize an UIAlertView so it doesn't cover the tab bar? I tried changing its frame property as it follows but it didn't work.

```
CGRect alertViewFrame = self.alertView.frame;
alertViewFrame.size.height = alertViewFrame.size.height - kTabBarHeight;
self.localizationDisabledView.frame = localizationDisabledViewFrame;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well the best option would be to subclass the uialertview, (I did it too, to change the background color of alertview from blue to gteen).

Comment: [According to Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) subclassing UIAlertView is actually not an option. "The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i am aware, you can't fiddle to much with alert view without getting anybody att apple review group angry but you can try with: 
https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView

It is nice little replacement for UIAlertView

Answer (score 0):

[Here's one solution](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZffqSGpAbE) which I picked up from the web:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My title"
                                                message:@"My message"
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];


alert.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
alert.transform = CGAffineTransformScale( alert.transform, 1.35, 1.35);
[alert show];
```

Notes: you can set your own values for the button titles, and for the delegate if you wish. When you look at the scaling factors 1.35 and 1.35 (for width and height), the larger the numbers become, the smaller the `UIAlertView` becomes and vice versa.